# How to copy ActiveWorkbook name to Clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba

The macro is supposed to open a new workbook, copy its name, and then use it within the same active workbook.

The MsgBox works just fine but copying this piece of information instead of displaying it gives me a headache.

Thanks!

```
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: How do you want to use the name? Can you explain a little bit more why you need to copy it to the Clipboard?

Comment: Hi BigBen, the name of the file is typically a country code, for instance, "CZ", which is then pasted in a range in column A (A2:A55, for example). It's just unusual that I can display it but not copy to use later on.

Comment: You'd be better off assigning the name to a variable and then populating cells with it (`myText = ActiveWorkbook.Name` followed by `Range("A2:A55").Value = myText`) or just doing it directly (`Range("A2:A55").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name`)

Comment: [Link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard) follow the link to get the text on Clipboard

Comment: As @cybernetic.nomad mentioned, you can assign directly. I don't see why you need the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you all! @cybernetic.nomad, it worked like a charm, thanks!